# Error in executing "android" specific shell command from java program in windows

Tags: android, shell, command-line, cmd, exec

I am trying to execute the following command in java.

```
android update project -p d:\code\android\projects\Testproject2
```

It executes fine in command-line and does exactly what is expected.

But, when I want to execute this command from java program. It gives error.

My java program code.

```
String cmd = "android update project -p d://code//android//projects//Testproject2";

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while(true){
            String line = b.readLine();
            if(line == null)break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("command execution failed");
    }
```

and the error I see in the console :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "android": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at com.test.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
command execution failed

It seems it can't find 'android' as a command while executing from java. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your cmd command and before the Android so it will look like this :

```
 String cmd = "cmd /c start  android update project -p d://code//android//projects//Testproject2";
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. but your solution doesn't seems to work for me - I'm using Ubuntu. any ideas? thanks.